# Intellij java.class template modification

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij and programming in java(i´m a beginner), the tool is excellent and my interest is to practice as much as i can, so that I'm interested in being able to modify the template java.class because when a new file is generated also produces file header and the line "public class" of automatic way and want it to generate and empty java.class file by way of practical reasons.

Please, could anyone teach me how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ does this by default when you ask it to create a new java class. If you still want to edit it, look in settings, file and code templates. You'll probably want to start with the `includes` file header to remove the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your thanks. Please tick the answer as correct and up-vote it.

Comment: I would like to vote, but i cant, im under 15 reputation frontier that alow me to vote.

Comment: There's some rep for you :)